# Why does UPPER() not work in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My SQL query selects some columns from from a view with an optional sort field.  Basically, my view concatenates a number of fields into a single address string, so that I end up with something like

```
123 Sesame Street Birdtown
```

in the address column.  I want the search to be case-insensitive (it isn't by default), so I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM BasicJobInfo WHERE UPPER(address) LIKE UPPER(searchString)
```

with searchString being the address that I want to find.  However, MySQL seems to be unable to convert address to UpperCase - I tried just calling

```
SELECT UPPER(address) FROM BasicJobInfo
```

but it doesn't change the case at all.  Any thoughts as to why this might be?
Also, any suggestions as to how else I can do a case-insensitive search?
Many thanks.

Comment: Can you include a desc of BasicJobInfo? I'm using Oracle, not MySQL, but could it be that the original datatype doesn't support "upper", and is converted to a string only at output?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [MySQL Reference Manual page on String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper):

> UPPER() is ineffective when applied to
>   binary strings (BINARY, VARBINARY,
>   BLOB).

Is it possible your `ADDRESS` column has a `BINARY`, `VARBINARY`, or `BLOB` data type?

If it is you will need to [convert the Binary String to an "ordinary" string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower).  For example:

```
UPPER(CONVERT(ADDRESS USING latin1))
```

Comment: Just to clarify, though, there are no BINARY, VARBINARY or BLOB types - address is just a concatenation of a number of INT and VARCHAR fields, so no idea why this was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please run the following queries:

```
SELECT  @@character_set_server, @@collation_server

SELECT  HEX(CAST(UPPER(address) AS binary)), HEX(CAST(address AS binary))
FROM    BasicJobInfo
```

Comment: latin1, latin1_swedish_ci

31323320436172726F747320506572746820, 31323320436172726F747320506572746820

Those last two are exactly the same as each other.

Answer (score 1):

This might come from encoding issues. Performing case-insensitive comparisons is described in the [appendix of the mysql help pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html). Example for case-insensitive UTF8 column/string comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE address LIKE 'searchString' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was use of keyword binary

```
  SELECT *
  FROM Table
  WHERE binary address = 'caseSensitiveString' ;
```